# How to have line chart "skip" data points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a unique issue. I have 4 people jump 3 times a week using a mat. I then take the max from each week a plot it. Well one of the 4 people wasn't able to show up for 2 weeks, but I still want them included in the line chart for a jump overview, but I keep getting the error
"Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 3 provided."

I have attached a picture of the graph and what the code is. In the picture the person who missed 2 weeks isn't included, so you can see what I want the graph to look like, just with the person added in.

[image]

```
Jump_vel_tracking <- ggplot(Jump_tibble, aes(x = game, y = daily_max_vel, color = athlete)) + 
scale_color_manual(values = c("red" , "blue", "purple")) +
geom_point() + 
geom_line(aes(group = athlete)) + 
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 3.0, to = 3.8, by = 0.1), limits = c(3.0, 3.8)) + 
labs(x = 'Game', y = 'Peak Velocity (m/s)', title = "Season CMJ Peak Velocity") +
theme(panel.background = element_rect (fill = 'gray88', colour = 'orange')) + 
theme(plot.background = element_rect (fill = 'orange', color = 'orange')) +
theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
theme(legend.position = 'none',
      legend.title = element_blank(),
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = 'orange'),
      legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'orange')) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 0)) +
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Jump_vel_tracking

```
enter code here
```

Comment: We need to see your data? On the missing weeks are they NA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error  `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 3 provided.` occurs when you have not supplied enough colours in your `scale_color_manual` for all the levels in a factor.

So you need a fourth colour if your `athlete` factor has four values in the dataset.

Edit - also to me (as a slightly colourblind person) that purple and blue are almost indistinguishable so maybe choose a different colour?